# How to multiple values between two dataframes based on row index and column name?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes:

DF1

```
            GOOG AAPL XOM  IBM  Cash
Date                               
2009-01-14  NaN  150  NaN  NaN  NaN
2009-01-21  NaN  -150 NaN  400  NaN
```

DF2

```
           GOOG AAPL  XOM  IBM Cash
Date                               
2009-01-14  NaN  100  NaN  NaN  NaN
2009-01-21  NaN  30   NaN  15   NaN
```

How do I multiply them so I can create a new DF that looks like this: 
I am basically trying to look at DF1, see if the index and the column exist in DF2, and if they do, multiply them together.

It is important to note that the indexes for DF1 and DF2 may not all be the same. So the answer must take that into account.

```
           GOOG AAPL   XOM  IBM Cash
Date                               
2009-01-14  NaN  15000 NaN  NaN  NaN
2009-01-21  NaN  -4500 NaN  6000 NaN
```

Comment: do you want to multiply the corresponding rows? or rows where the date is the same?

Comment: only rows where the date index is the same. the two datafiles may not have the same dates

Answer (score 2):

Use `concat` and `groupby.prod`:

```
df = pd.concat([df1,df2])
df.groupby(df.index).prod(min_count=1)
            GOOG   AAPL  XOM     IBM  Cash
Date                                      
2009-01-14   NaN  15000  NaN     NaN   NaN
2009-01-21   NaN  -4500  NaN  6000.0   NaN
```

Comment: does concat work if the indexes (the dates) are different though? there are dates in df2 that will not be in df1

Comment: @Shahab Yes they will. Different dates will form different groups in the result of `groupby.prod`.

Comment: just tried it. this doesn not seem to work.instead it is adding one df on top of the other

Comment: @Shahab Can you provide more detail?

Comment: this is the header columns when i print the code:     AAPL    GOOG     IBM Order  Shares Symbol    XOM

Comment: my apologies. used the wrong data frame. however, it is still incorrect. These are the following columns that are appearing. "AAPL  Cash    GOOG      IBM     SPY     XOM"- that's fine. however, it appears that it is simply pasting df2 under df1. none of the values are being multiplied, and the shared indexes are not "concatenated"

Comment: @Shahab can you post `print(df1.head())`, `print(df2.head())` ?

Comment: DF1:Symbol       AAPL   GOOG    IBM    XOM  Cash

Comment: DF2: GOOG   AAPL    XOM    IBM Cash

Comment: Did you also use the `groupby` after concatenating?

Answer (score 1):

Using [`DataFrame.mul`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html#pandas.DataFrame.mul) should handle the indexes:

```
df1.mul(df2)
```